# how to save this variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

The `thisvalue` span is a variable that I want to save in php. This variable changes dynamically by the code js. (this is the price in the shopping cart).

How to save this value in php so that I can later add it to the query in the mysql database?

```
<div id="cena"><b>Razem: </b><span class="thisvalue">0.00</span>zł</div>
```

Comment: Seems to me you may want to research AJAX and how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Here i could suggest you to use `jquery` to get value of your span and then send the value to another `php page` with `ajax`.

Below i write `jquery` to get the span value and send using ajax.

```
<script>
     var val = $('.thisvalue').text();
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: <your php file>,
     data: {value: val},
    success: success
    });
</script>
```

on the other hand you can get value with `$_POST` variable like this.

```
$value = $_POST['value']
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it eg by the post method? for example:   `<form method="post">
                    <div id="cena"><b>Razem: </b>
 <span name="kwota2">0.00</span> ...` and in php code: `$kwota2 = $_POST['kwota2'];`?

Comment: No you can not do it because post method fetched `value` inside tags by `$_POST['tag_name']` but here span tag can not contain `value` while it contains `text`.

Comment: so, if i've already used ajax above code, how to get up this data in php?

Comment: i updated it into code snnipet

Comment: you can add same file name but you have to use `isset` function so the particular php code will not execute everytime. when you use `isset` it checks for some `post` methos then its code executes.

Comment: use it like this `isset($_POST) { //code goes here to play with values }`

Comment: I can take this value in js, but I do not know how to pick it up in php. could you write it to me more easily?

Comment: try updated code to send value in `data` like this `data: {value: val}` and on `php` page get it with `value` index like `$_POST['value']`

Comment: `<script>
    var val = localStorage.getItem('sumalist');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {value: val},
        success: function () {
            console.log(val);
        }
    });
</script>`

Comment: I write this ^ js code and the console has a good value, but I can not pick it up in php.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['value']))
        {
            $value = $_POST['value'];
            echo ('lol');
        }`

Comment: first you have to check that if your ajax request has been sent or not to the `index.php` file. otherwise your code has not any issue.